# CSS Grid justify-content: stretch desn`t work

Tags: css, css-grid

I`m learning CSS Grid properties. And i am stuck on justify-content. start / end/ center etc works fine but : stretch dont.

I have tried changing properties like high,width etc in parent container, google also doesn`t know.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  min-width: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[class^="box-"] {
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  /*those values are exactly the same , like in fcc tutorial*/
  justify-content: stretch;
  /* nothing happens*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-1"> A </div>
    <div class="box-2"> B </div>
    <div class="box-3"> C </div>
    <div class="box-4"> D </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried changing properties like high,width etc in parent container, google also doesn`t know.

I want children boxes to strech along x axis of parent to full width size

[Screen from fcc tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooi5L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the effect of stretch if you define an `auto` sizing. Also note that stretch is the default value.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#algo-stretch):

> 11.8. Stretch auto Tracks
>
> This step expands tracks that have an auto max track sizing function by dividing any remaining positive, definite free space equally amongst them. If the free space is indefinite, but the grid container has a definite min-width/height, use that size to calculate the free space for this step instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  min-width: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[class^="box-"] {
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="justify-content: start;">
  <div class="box-1"> A </div>
  <div class="box-2"> B </div>
  <div class="box-3"> C </div>
  <div class="box-4"> D </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="justify-content: stretch;">
  <div class="box-1"> A </div>
  <div class="box-2"> B </div>
  <div class="box-3"> C </div>
  <div class="box-4"> D </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense. But i still think that fcc tutorial is misleading, especially for beginners like myself :)

Comment: @ArnoldRogalski not all the online tutorial are 100% correct or accurate so don't consider that what you read in the Net is 100% true unless it's from official resources. People writing for FCC are like you and me (you can also write for FCC)